# Grunt Copy is not copying files

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to copy some fonts into a directory named '`fonts`' To do this, I am trying to use the grunt-contrib-copy task. My task is setup like this:

```
fonts: {
  cwd: 'src/vendor/library/release/fonts',
  expand: false,
  src: [ '*' ],
  dest: 'build/temp/fonts/'
},
```

When this gets executed via grunt, the verbose output shows:

```
Running "copy:fonts" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.fonts exists in config...OK
Files: myfont.eot, myfont.svg, myfont.ttf, myfont.woff -> build/temp/fonts/
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[]
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[]
Copying myfont.eot -> build/temp/fonts/myfont.eot
Reading myfont.eot...ERROR
Warning: Unable to read "myfont.eot" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't my font files getting copied?

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you are running this on Windows? If so I am also having this issue.
On Mac osx it works fine which leads me to believe that it is a windows issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `expand` to `true`, and that works for me. 
Actually, I got this idea from you.

Reference: [grunt-contrib-copy reference](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)

Answer (score 0):

I had this very issue. What I found was I was using 'grunt-copy' and not 'grunt-contrib-copy'. I uninstalled grunt-copy with `npm uninstall grunt-copy` and ran `npm --save-dev grunt-contrib-copy` and things worked as expected.